# Display List of Iterated Data into two Columns in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have an array contains 6 objects, Now I need to render first 3 objects in 1st Column and Next 3 Objects in 2nd Column, Here I am Iterating the array with Map and Displaying the Data.
So How Can I break the Array into 2 Columns? As Of Now 6 objects are Displaying in one Column,
Can anyone Help me in this?
Thanks in Advance

```
<div className='section'>
                        <p>Display Here</p>
                              {dataservices.map((services,index)=>{
                                        return (
                                            <div className="skill-card" key={index} >
                                            <div className="skill-icon">{services.icon}</div>
                                            <label className="skill-name">{services.serviceName}</label>
                                          </div>
                                        )
                              })}
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here :

```
const secondColumnStart = Math.ceil(dataservices.length / 2);

      <div className='wholecontainer'>
                            <div className='col1'>
                                {dataservices.slice(0, secondColumnStart).map((services, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="skill-card" key={index} >
                                            <div className="skill-icon">{services.icon}</div>
                                            <label className="skill-name">{services.serviceName}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <div className='col2'>
                                {dataservices.slice(secondColumnStart).map((services, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="skill-card" key={index} >
                                            <div className="skill-icon">{services.icon}</div>
                                            <label className="skill-name">{services.serviceName}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Your map callback can be declared in a separate function, thereby avoiding repetition.